# Running rundll32.exe on WindowsXP

Tags: windows-xp, rundll32

[Using Rundll32.exe in Windows XP](http://best-windows.vlaurie.com/rundll32.html)

Can I pass some arguments like "Yes to all prompts" or "Return key to all prompts" to such commands?

Like we do while copy/pasting files and overwriting, etc.

**Edit**:
DLL in question:

`C:\Program Files\Sony Ericsson\Sony Ericsson PC Suite\RasCnxMngr.dll`

Command to open a GPRS session using saved connection is:

`C:\WINDOWS\system32\Rundll32.exe RasCnxMngr.dll,Rundll_Dial Aitel_GPRS`

I've little knowledge about DLLs. However, opening the DLL in binary mode I could find below strings together with "**Rundll_Dial**":

> RasCnxMngr.dll
>     **Rundll_Dial**
>     RasCM_CreateView
>     RasCM_ModuleInquire
>     RasCM_RemoveAllConnection
>     RasCM_RemoveConnection
>     _RasCM_ClearConnectionStatistics@4
>     _RasCM_Connect@16
>     _RasCM_Connection@12
>     _RasCM_ConnectionProperties@12
>     _RasCM_ConnectionWizard@12
>     _RasCM_Disconnect@4
>     _RasCM_Disconnection@8
>     _RasCM_EnumConnections@12
>     _RasCM_EnumConnectionsEx@16
>     _RasCM_GetConnectStatus@4
>     _RasCM_GetConnectionStatistics@8
>     _RasCM_GetConnectionStatus@8
>     _RasCM_GetDefaultConnection@4
>     _RasCM_GetFallbackConnection@8
>     _RasCM_GetRASHandle@4
>     _RasCM_HideConnections@4
>     _RasCM_Init@8
>     _RasCM_InitEx@12
>     _RasCM_ReadConnectionData@12
>     _RasCM_SetModemInfos@8
>     _RasCM_Uninit@4
>     _RasCM_ViewConnections@12
>     _RasCM_ViewLog@12

I would like to disconnect current connection and reconnect after a minute. Also, to suppress all prompts/confirmations.

Comment: Which DLL and which DLL function are you talking about?

Comment: @Jay I've edited the question for more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain the scenario before arival at the solution.

1. It's about connect/disconnect of GPRS sessions using a Mobile phone with an Indian Telecom Service Provider.
2. It's a dial-up service which involves PPP.
3. Windows XP, SP3 and with Sony Ericsson PC Suite

Problem: Usually when operator services requests over GPRS, they keep a validated session to bill accordingly. When session is closed so should be connection. Sometimes, my operator kept connection open but session closed. All the requests were dropped(not sure how). Usual session period is/was 50 minutes, after which I used to make a Dial-Up call using scheduled tasks. DLL approach was not helping as explained in the question.

However, few days back I came across, "rasdial" utility. Below two simple lines addressed the problem easily:

> rasdial "AirTel_GPRS" /DISCONNECT
>
> rasdial "AirTel_GPRS"

I've a created a **.bat** file with above commands, scheduled it every 50 minutes. Now I've an almost uninterrupted GPRS connection for downloads. :-)

[MicroSoft WinXP - Rasdial](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/rasdial.mspx?mfr=true)

And sevaral posts on **stackoverflow** regarding rasdial.

Thank you.

Comment: Also started using [NetworX](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/) tool to monitor my GPRS/EDGE bandwidth usage.